# Table, TR each 2 loop, PHP, HTML

Tags: html, loops, html-table, row

I got an html table, and I use some loop to get some data, this data is displaying this way:

```
<tr><td>Data</td></tr>
... next loop
```

But I wan't it to close table row (tr) every 2 or even 3 loops. So the data may look like this:

```
<tr>
<td>Data</td>
<td>Data1</td>
<td>Data2</td>
</tr>

...next loop...
```

Will you help me with this?

Comment: Can you post the code that are using for the looping?

Comment: while ($row = $db->fetch_array($query)) { , and then I just display the tr's and td's inside, but I wan't it to create the "trs" every 3 loops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have some counter in your loop you can use Modulus for this.

It's basically what's left of a number if you divide it.

Example:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 11; $i++) {
    if ($i % 2 === 0) {
        print('this is printed every two times');
    }
    if ($i % 3 === 0) {
        print('this is printed every three times');
    }
}
```

If you use a `foreach()` in stead you should just make a counter yourself (as Link stated you could also use the `key` of an array if it contains nice incremental keys):

```
$i = 1;
foreach($array as $item) {
    if ($i % 2 === 0) {
        print('this is printed every two times');
    }
    if ($i % 3 === 0) {
        print('this is printed every three times');
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Or in your specific case it would look something like:

```
print('<tr>');
$i = 1;
foreach($array as $item) {
    if ($i % 3 === 0) {
        print("</tr>\n<tr>");
    }
    print("<td>$item</td>\n");
    $i++;
}
print('</tr>');
```

The above is just a basic example.

You should also check whether the number of the columns is balanced and if not either add a colspan or an empty columns to balance it.

Comment: Instead of defining a variable $i it's cleaner (IMHO) to use $key instead as such: `foreach($array as $key => $item) { if ($key % 2 == 0) // Do something }`

Comment: @Link: you are right. OP should use it IF his indexes can be used.

Answer (score 4):

Using the modulo (%) operator is always a great solution for the problem you have above.
Since you didn't provide details about the implementation language, I've taken the liberty to provide you with a php example of how it's done.

```
<?php
    $breakPoint = 3;            // This will close the <tr> tag after 3 outputs of the <td></td> tags
    $data       = "Data";       // Placeholder of the data

    echo "<tr>";

    for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
    {
        echo "<td>{$data}</td>";

        if ($i % 3 == 0)
            echo "</tr><tr>";       // Close and reopen the <tr> tag
    }

    echo "</tr>";
?>
```