# Table, TR each 2 loop, PHP, HTML again

Tags: php, loops, html-table, rows

I've has help with the problem: [Table, TR each 2 loop, PHP, HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341371/table-tr-each-2-loop-php-html)

But it still doesn't work, so I post my loop structure, because if I add:

```
        if($i % 2 == 0) {
            echo '</tr><tr bgcolor="#4B4B4B">';
        }
```

It doesn't even close & re open the table row (tr).

Here is my loop structure:

```
    $similar .= '<table width="100%" bgcolor="#000" class="tbContent" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4">';
    $similar .= '<tr bgcolor="#4B4B4B">';
    while ($row = $db->fetch_array($query)) {
        $similar .= '
            <td>
                <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Pojedynek #' . $i . ':</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h1><a href="/' . $row["id"] . '/' . $row["link"] . '">' . $wT . '</a></h1>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <h1><a href="/' . $row["id"] . '/' . $row["link"] . '">' . $oT . '</a></h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    ' . $wContent . '
                        <td width="10%"><h2>przeciwko</h2></td>
                    ' . $oContent . '
                </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            ';
        if($i % 2 == 0) {
            echo '</tr><tr bgcolor="#4B4B4B">';
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $similar .= '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: just tested that weirdly enough, not initialising `$i` produces a notice but `$i++` dutifully produces 1 so it's not that

Comment: yeah, I've added $i = 0 before the 'while' loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `$i = 0` outside the loop, not initialising it means it will be initialised with zero every time your loop goes round and your if statement will either always fire or never fire

Comment: I did, just forget to paste it.