# Output recent Wordpress posts in tables, 2 posts wrapped in tr tag?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm designing a custom wordpress theme where I'd like to display the recent posts on the home page horizontally in tables, two posts per row. It would look like this:

http://www.numenfilm.com/preview/issues.php

So I'd like my index.php file to kick out code like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        post contents here
      </td>
      <td>
        post contents here
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        post contents here
      </td>
      <td>
        post contents here
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The table and td tags are easy. The problem I've having is getting the tr tags to wrap around the posts in groups of two.

I found this post elsewhere on stack overflow:

[Table, TR each 2 loop, PHP, HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341371/table-tr-each-2-loop-php-html)

The last suggestion seems to be what I'm looking for, but I haven't had any luck integrating it with wordpress.  Here's the code from my index.php page:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
  <div id="main_content">
  <h1><a href="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>">Numen News &amp; Blog</a></h1>
    <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    query_posts("showposts=5&paged=$paged");
    ?>

      <?php if (!is_single() && !is_page() && !is_front_page()) : ?><h1><?php wp_title(' ', true, 'right'); ?></h1><?php endif; ?>

        <?php /* begin the loop */ if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php if (is_page()) : /* show page contents */ ?>
                <div class="pagecontent" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <?php the_content('Read more &rarr;'); ?> 
                    <p><?php wp_link_pages('next_or_number=number&pagelink=page %'); ?></p>
                    <p><?php edit_post_link('Edit', '[ ', ' ]'); ?></p>  
                </div>
                <?php comments_template(); ?>

            <?php else : /* show post contents */ ?>
                <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <div class="postcontents">
                        <?php if (!is_single()) : ?>
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                        <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="posted">Posted <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_link(); ?> </div>
                        <?php the_content('Read more &rarr;'); ?> 
                        <p><?php wp_link_pages('next_or_number=number&pagelink=page %'); ?></p>    
                    </div>

                    <?php if(is_single) comments_template(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; /* end if page or post */ ?>
        <?php endwhile;/* end the main loop */ ?>

        <?php /* post navigation */ ?>
        <?php if (is_single()) : ?>
            <div class="postnavigation">
                <?php previous_post_link('%link', '<span>&larr;</span> Previous post') ?>
                <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next post <span>&rarr;</span>') ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
            <div class="postnavigation">
                <?php next_posts_link('Older posts <span>&rarr;</span>') ?>  
                <?php previous_posts_link('<span>&larr;</span> Newer posts') ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; /* end if have_posts */ ?>      
  </div><!--END main_content -->
<?php /* sidebar */ get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php /* footer */ get_footer(); ?>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use tables**.

If you want to continue to write bad markup you need to do something like this.

```
<table>
//wordpress loop starts ( you left that part out)
 <td>
   <tr>
     <?php the_content('Read more &rarr;'); ?>
   </tr>
  </td>
// loop ends
</table>
```

Comment: Though I normally don't use tables for anything structural they still have their advantages and I used them to create the equal heights achieved in the example above.  http://www.numenfilm.com/preview/issues.php Thanks for you suggestion, but if you look at the example I don't think your approach addresses what I'm going for.  Unless I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, the main code inside td is omitted for readability. the code I added and you should add are most in dark red color, I am sure you can figure that out.

```
  <table>
  <tr>
  <?php $counter=1; ?>
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
       <td>
       <?php if (is_page()) : /* show page contents */ ?>
           :
           :
        <?php endif; /* end if page or post */ ?>
        </td>
        <?php if($counter%2==0) echo '</tr><tr>';
              $counter++;
        ?>
    <?php endwhile;/* end the main loop */ ?>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Seems  pretty straight forward but now the page won't load.  I just get a white screen.  I just posted the new code at the end of my original question above (clunky, but stackoverflow doesn't seem to be letting me do it any other way).

Comment: have you added the code correctly, remeber the code missing on head,middle and foot in my answer. you have to fill in the missing code yourself.

Comment: Yup, I entered the missing code as per your instructions.  As far as I know I'm doing it correctly, but it's not working.  I have posted the edited index.php file above at the end of my oringal post (stackoverflow isn't letting me post it below).  Have a look?  See anything obvious?  Thanks a ton.

Comment: try to remove the code I want you to add and see if it loads. I don't think there is any problem with my code.

Comment: It loads perfectly without your code in place.  Would love for this to work out.  Any other suggestions?  Thanks again.

Comment: sorry, there is a mistake with my code: change this: $counter%2==0? echo '</tr><tr>'; **TO** $counter%2==0? echo '</tr><tr>': ' '; **OR** if($counter%2==0) echo '</tr><tr>';

Comment: Fantastic!  That's it.  Full code including solution posted below.  Thanks so much.

Comment: if it works, then you should accept the answer, so this is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code from index.php using the solution posted by bingjie2680 above.  It works.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

  <div id="main_content">

  <h1><a href="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>">Numen News &amp; Blog</a></h1>

    <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    query_posts("showposts=5&paged=$paged");
    ?>

      <?php if (!is_single() && !is_page() && !is_front_page()) : ?><h1><?php wp_title(' ', true, 'right'); ?></h1><?php endif; ?>

        <?php /* begin the loop */ if (have_posts()) : ?>

      <table>
        <tr>
        <?php $counter=1; ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
             <td>
             <?php if (is_page()) : /* show page contents */ ?>


                <div class="pagecontent" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <?php the_content('Read more &rarr;'); ?> 
                    <p><?php wp_link_pages('next_or_number=number&pagelink=page %'); ?></p>
                    <p><?php edit_post_link('Edit', '[ ', ' ]'); ?></p>  
                </div>
                <?php comments_template(); ?>


              <?php else : /* show post contents */ ?>

                <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <div class="postcontents">

                        <?php if (!is_single()) : ?>
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                        <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="posted">Posted <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_link(); ?> </div>

                        <?php the_content('Read more &rarr;'); ?> 
                        <p><?php wp_link_pages('next_or_number=number&pagelink=page %'); ?></p>    
                    </div>

                    <?php if(is_single) comments_template(); ?>
                </div>


        <?php endif; /* end if page or post */ ?>
            </td>
            <?php if($counter%2==0) echo '</tr><tr>';
                  $counter++;
            ?>
        <?php endwhile;/* end the main loop */ ?>
        </tr>
      </table>



        <?php /* post navigation */ ?>
        <?php if (is_single()) : ?>
            <div class="postnavigation">
                <?php previous_post_link('%link', '<span>&larr;</span> Previous post') ?>
                <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next post <span>&rarr;</span>') ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
            <div class="postnavigation">
                <?php next_posts_link('Older posts <span>&rarr;</span>') ?>  
                <?php previous_posts_link('<span>&larr;</span> Newer posts') ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endif; /* end if have_posts */ ?>      

  </div><!--END main_content -->

<?php /* sidebar */ get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php /* footer */ get_footer(); ?>
```